# React Hover Context Provider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I am trying to build a React Context that will let me know if a area is hovered over or not.

The issue I have currently is with the onMouseOver and onMouseOut which seem to occur a lot so the hover state switches from true to false frequently even though I am hovering over an area.

Here is what I have so far:

```
const { Provider, Consumer } = createContext({
    isHovering: false,
});

Provider.propTypes = {
    value: T.shape({
        isHovering: T.bool.isRequired,
    }),
};

function HoverContextProvider({ children }) {
    const [isHovering, setIsHovering] = useState(false);

    const value = {
        isHovering,
    };
    return (
        <Provider value={value}>
            <div
                onMouseOver={() => {
                    setIsHovering(true);
                }}
                onMouseOut={() => {
                    setIsHovering(false);
                }}
            >
                {children}
            </div>
        </Provider>
    );
}

HoverContextProvider.propTypes = {
    children: T.element.isRequired,
};

export { HoverContextProvider as default, Consumer as HoverContextConsumer };
```

What I do the is wrap an area with that like this:

```
<HoverContextProvider> some stuff in here, imagine a page header</HoverContextProvider>
```

Here is an visual reference:
[image]

So as i move my mouse around the green area (which contains lots of text), the isHovering state keeps switching from false to true - I guess because of the text.

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: You use `onMouseOver`. Consider using `onMouseEnter`

Comment: So it switches from false to true then straight away to false as mouseOut gets triggered

Comment: The `over` and `out` mouse events bubble, meaning that they will be triggered when the mouse moves over or out of any of the `children`. I think you want [mouseenter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseenter_event) and [mouseleave](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseleave_event) instead.

Comment: ah yes thanks! that does the trick!